# Hope below code is equivalent to Vlookup with formatting. any suggestions. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code which I came up to get all the source formating whenever I require a vlookup type operation in excel. I am also getting any formulas by this way. If there is a way to elimate the formula and get only the value and formating then it will be of great help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub finding()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Dim sFoundRange As String

    Dim range_to_copy As Range
    Dim range_to_paste As Range

    Dim ToFindString As String

    For i = 2 To 9

        ToFindString = ws.Cells(i, 1)

        On Error Resume Next:
        sFoundRange = ws1.Range("E1:E12").Find(ToFindString).Address

        Debug.Print sFoundRange

        Set range_to_copy = ws1.Range(Replace(sFoundRange, "E", "F"))
        Set range_to_paste = ws.Range("B" & i)

        range_to_copy.Copy
        range_to_paste.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a cell contains a formula, you might use the worksheet function `=FormulaText()`. I did a test with the `Formula` property of a range, but this did not work. (Maybe you might check if the first character is a `=` sign)